# Playing Flash .swf file in android?

Tags: android, flash

I have this code :

```
         package flash.play;

       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
     import android.webkit.WebView;


     public class flashplay extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    String url ="file:///android_asset/abcd.swf";



    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    wv.loadUrl(url);

}
 }
```

But I am getting just a white screen on emulator Can anyone please help me play this file on Webview?

Comment: I don't think you can play it with emulator, you should test it on a physical device.

Comment: test it on device with froyo (2.2) or greater and make sure you have the flash player from the google play store installed on the device.

Comment: Can u tell which player I shud use?

Comment: I have installed it ,But still getting a white screen,(I am using 2.3.6 ).Do I need to mention any other attribute in manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to your AndroidMainfest.xml

**android:hardwareAccelerated = "true"**

Answer (score 0):

You should test it on a device. not on emulator

Comment: It still show a block in webview when i test it on device ... Do i need to install flash player.If yes which one ?

Comment: try this. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer&hl=en

Comment: I have installed it ,But still getting a white screen,(I am using 2.3.6 ).Do I need to mention any other attribute in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

What I did with mine is I created an html file and call my html file in WebView. inside my html file I use swfobject to load my swf file. I hope this helps someone.